# Youtube iframe: How to hide author in an embedded player?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

In an embedded iframe, before the video plays, the author's avatar displays at the upper left corner of the player; also for a short while after the video start to play, the avatar will appear at the lower right corner. 
Is it possible to prevent them from showing in these two occasions?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I have not been able to determine a way to do that. The YT Player does provide for the "modestbranding" parameter to remove the "YouTube" logo. I found no parameter that removes the author's avatar.